# Does Chrome for Android implement tab discarding, and how to access its controls?

Tags: chrome-for-android

I'm trying to diagnose an issue on my Android. See below for more background on the underlying issue. But what I want to ask you now is why I can't seem to find anything in my Android Chrome (version 71) related to Chrome's "tab discarding". (For background on tab discarding and page refreshes, see http://superuser.com/questions/1353931/how-can-i-get-chrome-to-stop-killing-my-tabs-in-the-background/1353940.) I want to see if tab discarding might be the cause of my problem, but it's hard to diagnose because I can't find the parts of Chrome relating to tab discarding.

In particular, there are supposed to be tab discarding-related flags at chrome://flags, but I can't find any. There's also supposed to be a tool for learning about tab discarding information, at chrome://discards, but Chrome says that's an invalid link. (These flags/features *do* appear on my desktop version of Chrome 71, though.) It makes me wonder if my Android build of Chrome even does tab discarding.

As for the underlying issue I'm trying to debug: I have this webapp/website/webapge that uses JavaScript to play audio. I want this page to keep playing its audio indefinitely on my phone, even when Chrome isn't the foreground app. This works properly for a while (10-30 minutes maybe), but eventually Chrome will reload the page for no obvious reason. My current hypothesis is that it maybe has something to do with tab discarding.

Answer (score 0):

Your device is out of memory. Like your Android phone or tablet, Chrome is silently closing background tabs in order to make memory available. When you click on one of those tabs it reloads.

Comment: That's very plausible, but are there any tools in Chrome that would help me verify that this is the cause of a *particular* tab being reloaded? (They have some on OS X Chrome, but I can't find them on Android Chrome.) Similarly, is there any way to turn off this tab-closing behavior on Android, ideally on a site-by-site basis?